# FFmpeg & Black and White Conversion

Tags: ffmpeg

How to convert a video to black and white using `ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 41):

## Desaturate

Use the [hue filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hue) if you want to desaturate:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf hue=s=0 output
```

This is like using *Colors* → *Saturation* in the GIMP.

## Grayscale

Use the [format filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format-1) if you want to convert to grayscale format:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf format=gray output
```

This is like using *Image* → *Mode* → *Grayscale* in the GIMP.

## Threshold

See [FFmpeg convert video to Black & White with threshold?](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/28759)

This is like using *Colors* → *Threshold* in the GIMP.

Comment: @llogan whats the difference between desaturate and grayscale? I tried both on my vid file, the results looked similar.

Comment: @joedotnot Desaturate removes the color, but does not change the image color mode. This is like using Colors → Saturation in the GIMP. Grayscale converts it to gray mode (from YUV or RGB). This is like using Image → Mode → Grayscale in the GIMP. Some formats don't support gray mode, so ffmpeg will just automatically convert it back to YUV or RGB but the color is gone so it will look similar regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a YUV video format like mp4, you likely don't want to use format=gray.

format=gray adds a 0 usage of every 7th pixel.  This slightly shifts the image brighter and leaves gaps in the intensities.

Instead use extractplanes=y.  It works correctly and maybe less processing.  It's also better than the other options, like hue=s=0 or monothat keep 3 planes instead of 1 for memory usage, etc.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf extractplanes=y output.mp4
```

It's easiest to see using a histogram comparison.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "split [s1][s2]; [s1] format=gray,histogram [so1]; [s2] extractplanes=y,histogram [so2]; [so1][so2] vstack" histogram.mp4
```