# How to convert rgb video to grayscale and save it?

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I am converting an rgb video to grayscale video and saving it as a new video by using OpenCV 3.4 and Python 2. However, there existed some problems. For example, video becomes corrupted grayscale video. When I modify the code a little bit, I cannot get grayscale video. It is also worth to mention that saved video is too slow. I think its speed is about fps but I could not also figure it out. A screen shot from the corrupted video:

[image]

I have tried a code which is generally used by people on the internet. However, I could not get what I wish. Here is the code that corrupts my video. All in all, My actual aim is to convert the rgb video to grayscale and save it. How can I do that ?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('example.mp4')

ret, frame = cap.read()
print('ret =', ret, 'W =', frame.shape[1], 'H =', frame.shape[0], 'channel =', frame.shape[2])


FPS= 20.0
FrameSize=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0])
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')

out = cv2.VideoWriter('Video_output.avi', fourcc, FPS, FrameSize, 0)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    frame = gray

    # Save the video
    out.write(frame)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
         break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For this code, It also gives this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, 
file /home/deep/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 11048
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ColorConverter1.py", line 20, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /home/deep/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:11048: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

The source code is here: https://gist.github.com/vscv/f7ef0f688fdf5e888dadfb8440830a3d

Comment: Why not just use `ffmpeg`?

Comment: If you talk about codec type (fourcc), I could make it working only this way. When I use other types, It gave errors.

Comment: No, I am not talking about a codec. `ffmpeg` is a highly optimised, stand-alone program - no need for OpenCV.

Comment: I will look into that. However, as of now, I am really curious about solving this problem to understand the logic. But still, what is the command for doing this with ffmpeg ? @MarkSetchell

Comment: I'm no expert, but here is an example to try... https://stackoverflow.com/a/32385256/2836621

Comment: Your code saved a non-corrupted grayscale video for me using an MJPG-encoded AVI as input.  Does your video *display* non-corrupted?  Also, your error may be avoidable by adding `if not ret: break` after `cap.read()`.

Comment: you are right about video-display. When I define the output as .avi, the video is corrupted. When I define it as .mp4, video is okay. Although thsi is not a big problem, how can I solve this issue ? @UlrichStern

Comment: I have been writing MJPG-encoded AVIs with various versions of OpenCV and have not had problems.  May still be an OpenCV bug, or your video player has issues with the AVI.  Note that for MP4, the FOURCC values can possibly not be generated with `VideoWriter_fourcc()`, see [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#ac3478f6257454209fa99249cc03a5c59).